# ¿Cómo subir archivo con Django no model?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo subir un archivo con Django, utilizando formulario sin necesidad de crear un campo en algún modelo sin utilizar modelo.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/uploads
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')
```

Quiero subir el archivo y guardarlo en la carpeta `/tmp/` de mi sistema.

Comment: Hola, ¿cuál es el problema?, ¿has intentado simplemente usar `upload_to='/tmp'`?, ¿te arroja un error?

Comment: el problema es que NO quiero guardar informacion del archivo en la base de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he conseguido ;)

bueno despues de tantas busquedas y pruebas he lo eh podido realizar de la siguente manera

1. crear el formulario normal en forms.py ej:

`class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField(required=False)`

1. en el template en el formulario asegurarse de incluir la etiqueta **enctype="multipart/form-data".** esto con metodo POST
2. Cuando recojo los datos en la vista los recogo con request.FILES
3. en este punto ya me ayudo con la documentacion [Basic file uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads)
4. comparto mi codigo la parte interesante en le metodo POST:

import os

class IndexA(View):

```
template_name = 'forms.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('index:ani')
success_message = "%(name)s was created successfully"
form_class = UploadFileForm()


def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(
        request,
        self.template_name,
        {  'form' : self.form_class,
        }
      )

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    def handle_uploaded_file(file, filename):
        if not os.path.exists('upload/'):
            os.mkdir('upload/')
        with open('upload/' + filename, 'wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in file.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)

    form = UploadFileForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES['file'])

    if form.is_valid():
        handle_uploaded_file(self.request.FILES['file'], str(self.request.FILES['file']))

    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()


    return render(
        request,
        self.template_name,
        {  'form' : self.form_class,
        }
    )
```